# RangeValidator not working in web user control

Tags: asp.net, web-user-controls, rangevalidator

I am creating an calendar control using ajax calendar extender.In that control i need to validate date from and to.For that i use asp RangeValidator control.Calander formate is set to [MM/dd/yyyy].

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RGvDt" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Date" 
        ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtDate" Type="Date">
</asp:RangeValidator>
```

But it is not working.It allays troughs error

```
The value '01/31/2022' of the MaximumValue property of 'RGvDt' cannot be converted to type 'Date'.
```

But this code works fine in aspx page.Can any one tell me how can i use RangeValidator into my user control.And how can i change validation format to [dd/MM/yyyy]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/` has a special meaning in a date format string. It means: "replace me with your curent culture's date separator". In germany for example it is `.`.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator)

> The "/" custom format specifier represents the date separator, which
>   is used to differentiate years, months, and days. The appropriate
>   localized date separator is retrieved from the
>   `DateTimeFormatInfoDateSeparator` property of the current or specified
>   culture. ...

I think the only way is using a `CustomValidator` to check this format. Then you can parse the date in this way(on serverside):

```
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(txtDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    // now there is a valid date in dt
}
```

Notice the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` which i have used to enforce the `/` as actual date separator.